# How to import module from index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, maplibre-gl

I created an example `node.js` project:

```
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
```

**Here is the `index.js` (two rows only):**

```
"use strict";
import MapLibreGlDirections, { LoadingIndicatorControl } from "@maplibre/maplibre-gl-directions";
```

Install the "`@maplibre/maplibre-gl-directions`" in global:

```
# npm install "@maplibre/maplibre-gl-directions" --global
```

**Now, run the `index.js` with node:**

```
# node index.js
```

**Here is the error:**

```
node:internal/errors:496
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@maplibre/maplibre-gl-directions' imported from /root/Documents/test/index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:890:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:939:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1132:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:835:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v18.18.2
```

I copied the "import" from here:
https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-directions

The package "`@maplibre/maplibre-gl-directions`" has already `been installed in global, but` index.js `still can't find the module` (ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND).

What's wrong in the index.js? How to import that module?

**Update:**

After installing `vite` in global with `npm`, try to build with the following files and contents but it's not working.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**index.js:**

```
"use strict";
import MapLibreGlDirections, { LoadingIndicatorControl } from "@maplibre/maplibre-gl-directions";

console.log("hello world in console");

function hello() {
  document.write("hello world in document")
}

module.exports = hello;
```

**index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  hello world in body!
  <script type="javascript">
    new hello()
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**After running:**

```
# npm run build
# npm run preview
```

**Here is the output in Firefox:**

```
hello world in body!
```

**Here is  the expected output in Firefox:**

```
hello world in body! 
hello world in document!
```

The `vite` is not building the "`index.js`" in the project. How to make this example project work with `vite` build?

**Update 2:**

**After adding in script:**

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

**Then rebuild with: npm run build**

```
error during build:
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "@maplibre/maplibre-gl-directions" from "/root/Documents/test/index.js".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
```

It's still can't find the module with `vite`, it's the same as `node`. What's the problem for importing that module from `index.js`?

**Update 3:**

**vite.config.js: (one row only)**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
```

**Then rebuild:**

```
failed to load config from /root/Documents/test/vite.config.js
error during build:
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'vite' imported from /root/Documents/test/vite.config.js.timestamp-1710392651394-3723eb717de11.mjs
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:916:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:973:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1193:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:403:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:372:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:249:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36)
```

The same `ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this package in a browser environment rather than using Node to execute it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@maplibre/maplibre-gl-directions": "^0.6.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.64",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.21",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.1.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.1.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

```
// Import the plugin
import MapLibreGlDirections, { LoadingIndicatorControl } from "@maplibre/maplibre-gl-directions";

// Make sure to create a MapLibreGlDirections instance only after the map is loaded


function App() {
  console.log(MapLibreGlDirections);
  console.log(LoadingIndicatorControl);
  return (
    <>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

[image]

**plese check dist folder**

[image]

Comment: I want to build my package to import that module, and then use my package in the browser. Is it possible?

Comment: sure. You need to use some package building tools. Webpack, Vite library mode, tsup, etc.

Comment: I often use Vite to build my own packages and publish them on npm. This article may help you. https://rbardini.com/how-to-build-ts-library-with-vite/

Comment: I tried to build with vite but not work, can you help to check my updated post? Thank you.

Comment: I have added update 2, it's the same error when building with vite. Please help to check.

Comment: I have added `vite.config.js` in the "`update 3`", the same `module not found` for the globally installed `vite` package.

Comment: Please provide me with your code repository on GitHub. I'm in the East Eighth District. In the evening, I will pull the code you provided and help you look at this problem. How about it?

Comment: Thank you, I have just created my very first "node.js" project in my local documents folder. All files have been listed in the post. I'm trying to build the module with my own package, and then use my package as a "wrapper" of the import module. I want to use these simple few files for studying the node.js.

Comment: https://github.com/kbysiec/vite-vanilla-ts-lib-starter I searched and this project can solve your problem. `src/index.ts` Here is the package entry for the entire project. But I don't know if you are familiar with `Typescript`. Packaging your own npm package requires mastering the configuration details of many configuration tools. I recommend referring to the relevant project templates.